# Convergence of certain integral over torus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Define $F(t_1,s_1,t_2,s_2)=$
$$\big((2+\cos t_1)\cos s_1 - (2+\cos t_2)\cos s_2\big)^2 + \big((2+\cos t_1)\sin s_1-(2+\cos t_2)\sin s_2\big)^2 + (\sin t_1 -\sin t_2 )^2,$$
on $[0,2\pi]\times[0,2\pi]\times[0,2\pi]\times[0,2\pi].$

Does the following integral converge

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(2+\cos t_1)(2+\cos t_2)\,dt_1\,ds_1\,dt_2\,ds_2}{F(t_1,s_1,t_2,s_2)}?$$